# Scala Collections - Making a new array from an existing using certain rules

Tags: arrays, scala, scala-collections

I'm trying to make a function in Scala that when -

`println(thisIsAFunction(Array(1,1,4,5,4,4)))`

is called, it will give me a new array that is always half the size of the array input (the array input will always be an even number and bigger than 2), and in the new array it will not contain the same number twice. So for example, in the above statement, it would return an array consisting of the numbers 1, 4 and 5. I have been trying to approach this a number of ways but can't get my head round it.

Comment: What have you tried? What if they are not duplicates? What if the output array run out of space? Will it always be numbers or may it be anything? Does it has to be an array?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It will always be numbers, always an array, always an even size

Comment: That doesn't answer all the questions. What happens if the input array doesn't have any duplicates, the output is a half size, which elements should be there? Does the order of the elements matter in the output? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

```
def thisIsAFunction(a: Array[Int]) =
  a.distinct.take(a.length/2)
```

The `distinct` method removes any duplicates from the `Array` so that it does not contain the same number twice.

The `take` methods reads the first `n` elements of the result, so `take(a.length/2)` gives an `Array` that is half the length of the original.

Comment: I'd recommend explaining your answer instead of just posting code.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I would recommend asking for an explanation rather than downvoting. Save downvotes for answers that are actually wrong or misleading. Either way it is good manners to explain why the downvoted was given.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted, you asked for an explanation, I gave a likely one. That said, with 13k+ points I would expect that you already know these types of expectations for answers, and likely the downvoter did to.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I wasn't meaning to suggest that you downvoted or to criticise you for your comment, so I'm sorry if it came across that way. I know you were just trying to help. I do usually add an explanation, but in this case I guess I just thought the code was self-explanatory (and I was in a hurry!). Anyway, I've added the explanation so I hope the answer is now OK. If not it would be nice if the person who downvoted let me know how to make it better.